# Не устанавливается mpi на windows 64bit

Tags: windows, visual-studio, mpi

При установки mpi на windows 64 bit, запуске кода на visual studio

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include "mpi.h"

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
 int ProcNum, ProcRank, RecvRank;
 MPI_Status Status;
 MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);
 MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &ProcNum);
 MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &ProcRank);
 if ( ProcRank == 0 ){
 // Действия, выполняемые только процессом с рангом 0
 printf("\n Hello from process %3d", ProcRank);
 for (int i = 1; i < ProcNum; i++ ) {
 MPI_Recv(&RecvRank, 1, MPI_INT, MPI_ANY_SOURCE,
 MPI_ANY_TAG, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &Status);
 printf("\n Hello from process %3d", RecvRank);
 }
 }
 else // Сообщение, отправляемое всеми процессами,
 // кроме процесса с рангом 0
 MPI_Send(&ProcRank,1,MPI_INT,0,0,MPI_COMM_WORLD);
 MPI_Finalize();
 return 0;
}
```

выводит такую ошибку
[image: ошибки]

Прописано:
Свойства-> C/C++ -> Общие -> Дополнительные каталоги включаемых файлов: mpi/include
Свойства-> Компоновщик -> Общие -> Дополнительные каталоги библиотек: mpi/lib
Свойства-> Компоновщик -> Ввод -> Дополнительные зависимости: msmpi.lib

Скачано msmpisdk.msi и MSMpiSetup.exe. Проверено, что все установлено set MPI

Помогите, не хочет устанавливаться и все. Не знаю, что и делать.

---